# getting error while updating the angular version, npm ERR! While resolving: metronic-angular@6.1.8

Tags: angular, npm, metronic

I have project in angular 8 with metronic after updating to angular 10 when I try to install `npm i` every time getting this error.

`npm ERR! While resolving: metronic-angular@6.1.8`

`npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@10.2.5`

```
  npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree.
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! While resolving: metronic-angular@6.1.8
  npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@10.2.5
  npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common.
  npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^10.2.5" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@8.2.3
  npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
  npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^8.2.3" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

here is the screenshot.

[image: error screen]

any help will be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: metronic-angular is a paid template? Did a bit of googling doesn't seem they have version 6 anywhere anymore to look into. What it does look like is metronic-angular@v6 does not support angular 10+ only v8 and v9 based on the error log. You can try --legacy-peer-deps or --force but you may or may not encounter issues.

Comment: so any answer how can I upgrade it with anuglar?

Comment: Best bet is to contact the developer, as they seem to have version 7 and 8 of metronic-angular which support higher version of angular. I don't know if you need to pay or not for those version but as of now there's nothing you can do with metronic-angular@6.1.8 with any angular version >9.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach the package.json please? It looks like  `@angular/cdk` has not been increased to v10. I recently had a similar issue while updating angular even with the correct version specified. I fixed by:

- Deleting node_modules - can be done via command `rm -rf node_modules`
- Deleting package-lock.json
- Re-running `npm install`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry don't have enough rep to add a comment, have edited to make more of an answer

Comment: I've try this many times but  didn't worked.

Comment: @n_dev have you tried to do ng update again? cause it seems like your angular/cdk is still 8 as it's said above.

Comment: yes I've follow the insturctions  
https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.2-10.0